# How to find the total between the dates for each values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
Period  datefrom   dateto      code  id

01/2012 18/12/2011 28/12/2011  A     Emp1
01/2012 11/01/2012 14/01/2012  B     Emp1
02/2012 20/12/2011 25/12/2011  A     Emp2
02/2012 01/02/2012 08/01/2012  B     Emp2 'from and to date is greater than current date.
.....
```

i want to take total of value between datefrom and dateto with system date validation

Expected Output

```
ID     PERIOD   A  B TOTAL

Emp1   01/2012  11 4 15
Emp2   02/2012  6  0 6
```

'B is 0 because from and to date is greater than current date.

How to make a query for this calcuatlion..?

Any suggestions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

SELECT
    ID,
    Period,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,datefrom,dateto) + 1),0)
        FROM Test 
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,datefrom,dateto) > 0 and code = 'A'
        and x.Period = Period and x.id = id)
     as ACode,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,datefrom,dateto) + 1),0)
        FROM Test 
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,datefrom,dateto) > 0 and code = 'B'
        and x.Period = Period and x.id = id)
     as Bcode
FROM TABLENAME x
GROUP BY
    Period,
    ID
```

The plus one added to the date diff is to account for part days.