# DATEADD with part days

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a little trouble getting a count of dates in SQL SERVER. I require the number of calender days between 2 dates start and ends dates included. The problem with the example below is that it always returns 10 when I believe it should be 11.

```
DECLARE @FROM DATETIME, @TO DATETIME
SET @FROM = '18/12/2011 00:00:00'
SET @TO = '28/12/2011 00:00:00'

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FROM,@TO), -- Returns 14459
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,@FROM,@TO), -- Returns 241
    DATEDIFF(DAY,@FROM,@TO), -- Returns 10
    CEILING(CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR,@FROM,@TO) / 24) as DECIMAL(9,5))) --Returns 10
    CEILING(CAST(CEILING(CEILING(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@FROM,@TO) as DECIMAL(18,5))) / 60) / 60 as DECIMAL(9,5)) / 24) --Returns 10
```

The bottom line works if there is at least 1 second between the times but I must account for all scenarios.

My only other thought was to simply add one to the date diff to account for the part days? Is that reliable?

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,@FROM,@TO) + 1
```

I came across when answering this question [How to find the total between the dates for each values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043159/how-to-find-the-total-between-the-dates-for-each-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is an expression that can be resolved to a time, date, smalldatetime,
>   datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value. date can be an
>   expression, column expression, user-defined variable or string
>   literal. startdate is subtracted from end date.

This is taken from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

28-18 = 10.  I think you will always have to add 1 in the scenario you have because of the definition for DATEDIFF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the @TO date to:

```
SET @TO = '28/12/2011 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks but the dates are an example - They would not be fixed normally and the example values could potentially occur. A solution would ideally work with 00:00:00 times set :)

Comment: What we do is ignore the time and always set the time for start date to 0:00:00 and end date the time to 23:59:59 for these type of calcs or queries where you need selection beween two dates.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of days between two dates (ignoring the time of day), including the start and end date, try;

```
SELECT FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, @TO))-FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, @FROM))+1
```

Edit:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @FROM, @TO)+1
```

seems to return the exact same results, which would indeed make it a more elegant way of doing it. Always thought DATEDIFF timeparts were about truncating after the calculation (which would give the wrong result if the start time was later in the day than the end time) and not truncating before the calculation which gives the correct result for your case. You learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a close equivalent of the C# `DateTime.TotalDays()` function (i.e. to know fractional days) you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '10 Apr 2012 15:00'
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '12 Apr 2012 16:00'

SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)) / 86400
```

*Note: 86400 = seconds in a day = 24 hours x 60 mins x 60 seconds